# Beautifulsoup not finding table cell value

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, html-parsing

I am trying to get the value in column 5 of an HTML table, depending on the value of column 1. So far, I am only trying to print all the cells in all the rows of the table.

The html:[the html table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hcLZY.png)

My script:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "D:\opus\lt-report-opus_lmes_jenkins-20180510-111740\index.html"
page = open(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.read(), 'html.parser')

table = soup.find('table', attrs={'id': 'statisticsTable'})
if table != None:
    print ('Found the table ' + str(table))

for row in table.findChildren('tr'):
    print (row)
    for cell in row.findChildren('td'):
        print (cell)
        print (cell.text)
```

I find the table OK.
The problem is that 'row' is not finding the rows within the table. And so nothing is ever printed.

Why?

Comment: Give(PRINT) the piece of html content so that we can fetch the table data. image wont work

Comment: try using `find_all('tr')` or paste your file for us to see